# When right clicking on an element I get an "uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::DriverExtensions::HasInputDevices (NameError)" error

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, debian, watir-webdriver

After upgrading all my ruby gems including *watir-webdriver* to the latest *v0.9.9* I got the below error when my script tries to right click on an element

[image]

Below is the code that executes the **And I right click on layer 1 in the import tab** step

```
def select_layer_import_tab(layer_num)
  layer_index = (layer_num.to_i - 1)
  @browser.divs(:class => "legend")[layer_index].img.click
  @browser.divs(:class => "legend")[layer_index].img.right_click    <--------------------- error happens here ------------
end
```

Here are my gems list versions **prior** to upgrade:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
childprocess (0.5.8, 0.5.7)
chunky_png (1.3.5)
cucumber (2.1.0)
cucumber-core (1.3.0)
data_magic (0.21)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
faker (1.6.1)
ffi (1.9.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gherkin3 (3.1.2)
headless (2.2.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
oily_png (1.2.0)
page-object (1.1.0)
page_navigation (0.9)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (10.4.2, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
require_all (1.3.3)
rspec (3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.1)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.4.0)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
testgen (0.8.7)
thor (0.19.1)
watir-webdriver (0.9.1)
websocket (1.2.2)
yard (0.8.7.6)
yml_reader (0.5)

Here are my gems list versions **post** upgrade:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.3.2, 1.2.0)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
bundler (1.15.2, 1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
childprocess (0.7.1, 0.5.8, 0.5.7)
chunky_png (1.3.8, 1.3.5)
connection_pool (2.2.1)
cucumber (2.4.0, 2.1.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0, 1.3.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
data_magic (1.0, 0.21)
diff-lcs (1.3, 1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
faker (1.6.1)
ffi (1.9.18, 1.9.10)
gem-wrappers (1.3.0, 1.2.7)
gherkin (4.1.3)
gherkin3 (3.1.2)
headless (2.3.1, 2.2.0)
i18n (0.8.6, 0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.6, 0.4.2)
json (2.1.0, 1.7.7)
minitest (5.10.2, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
oily_png (1.2.1, 1.2.0)
page-object (1.1.0)
page_navigation (0.10, 0.9)
power_assert (1.0.2)
psych (2.2.4, 2.0.0)
rake (12.0.0, 10.4.2, 0.9.6)
rdoc (5.1.0, 4.0.0)
require_all (1.4.0, 1.3.3)
rspec (3.6.0, 3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.6.0, 3.4.1)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0, 3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0, 3.4.0)
rspec-support (3.6.0, 3.4.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.1, 1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium-webdriver (3.4.4, 2.48.1)
test-unit (3.2.5, 2.0.0.0)
testgen (0.9, 0.8.7)
thor (0.19.4, 0.19.1)
watir-webdriver (0.9.9, 0.9.1)
websocket (1.2.4, 1.2.2)
yard (0.9.9, 0.8.7.6)
yml_reader (0.7, 0.5)

Other environment information:

- Debian Linux Wheezy v7.1
- ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749)
- Chrome Browser v45.0.2454.85
- Using xvfb to render the above browser in a headless linux environment
- ChromeDriver 2.20.353124

I've tried looking around on forums for this specific error but can't find anything. I also wanted to try upgrading to the latest Chrome browser and Chromedriver version however it would appear that the latest version of the google chrome browser no longer supports Debian Wheezy so I am stuck with what I got.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried using **watir v6.4.3** instead of **watir-webdriver v0.9.9** and the error does not happen. Would still love to know why the error is happening with watir-webdriver?

Comment: Watir-Webdriver v0.9.9 is very old. Watir v6.4.3 is the latest version of Watir-Webdriver - ie the name was migrated due to the drop in support of Watir-Classic. I don't remember exactly what changed in which version, but I would guess the problem is related to the changes in Selenium-Webdriver 2 vs 3.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JustinKo

Comment: @Costa thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium 3 removed Driver Extension checks for input that `watir-webdriver` accessed directly. Updating code to latest Watir version will fix this. (as well as provide a number of extra functions and performance improvements).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @titus fortner

Comment: @Costa: if this answer is sufficient, please consider accepting it (which helps keep SO neat and tidy).

Comment: @orde: I tried to vote for this answer but the system told me I didn't meet a certain criteria to show my vote although it logged my acceptance internally.